# Getting errors and cannot see the mistake creating a console menu

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, cannot-find-symbol

This is the code producing 2 errors (I apologise as this is my first time using this site and not completely sure how to do everything but the errors have been flagged at the m of menu in the first error and the s of scanchoice of the second error)

> java:22: error: cannot find symbol choiceentry = menu();
>
> java:52: error: cannot find symbol choiceentry = scanchoice.nextInt();

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Student
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int choiceentry;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        choiceentry = menu();
            while (choiceentry != 6)
            {
                if(choiceentry == 1) 
                {
                // ..do something
                }
                else if(choiceentry == 2)
                {
                //..something else
                }
                else if(choiceentry == 3)
                {
                //...something else
                }
                else if(choiceentry == 4)
                {
                // ..something else
                }
                else if(choiceentry == 5)
                {
                //..something else
                }
                else if(choiceentry == 6)
                {
                System.exit(0);
                }
                else
            {
            System.out.println("Enter \"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\" or \"6\"");
            choiceentry = scanchoice.nextInt();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

This is the code I have used to setup the menu and it is building fine

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Enroll
{

//Creation of Console Menu
    public static int menu()
        {
        int selection;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        /***************************************************/

        System.out.println("Please Select an Option:");
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println("0 - Input Course Details");
        System.out.println("1 - Search");
        System.out.println("2 - Add Student");
        System.out.println("3 - Delete Student");
        System.out.println("4 - Report (Percentage of M & F Students)");
        System.out.println("5 - Save");
        System.out.println("6 - Quit");

        selection = input.nextInt();
        return selection;    
        }
//End Menu
}
```

Comment: I wonder when your program should enter the `else if(choiceentry == 6)` branch, because the loop will stop if `choiceentry` is *6*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  Good catch @Tom, I just added a modification to the answer that should take care of the `!= 6` case.

You need to access the `menu()` function through the `Enroll` class like this:

```
choiceentry = Enroll.menu();
```

Note that your only method `menu()` in the `Enroll` class is static, so you don't need to create an instance of the `Enroll` class.

This line:

```
choiceentry = scanchoice.nextInt();
```

Should be this in order to use the `Scanner` reference:

```
choiceentry = input.nextInt();
```

One more thing, it looks like you want the user to be able to enter multiple commands until they choose to quit.  Take a look at the use of the `hasAnswered` flag in the code below.

Code with changes:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Student
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int choiceentry;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        choiceentry = Enroll.menu(); //Access through the Enroll class
        if(choiceentry == 6)
        {
             //Exit if user entered 6
             System.exit(0);
        }

          while (true) //I hate to put while(true) in code, but it seems appropriate here
          {
                boolean hasAnswered = false; //use a flag to determine if the user entered a valid command
                if(choiceentry == 1) 
                {
                  hasAnswered = true;
                // ..do something
                }
                else if(choiceentry == 2)
                { 
                  hasAnswered = true;
                //..something else
                }
                else if(choiceentry == 3)
                {
                  hasAnswered = true;
                //...something else
                }
                else if(choiceentry == 4)
                {
                  hasAnswered = true;
                // ..something else
                }
                else if(choiceentry == 5)
                {
                  hasAnswered = true;
                //..something else
                }
                else
                {
                  System.out.println("Enter \"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\" or \"6\"");
                  choiceentry = input.nextInt(); //use the Scanner

                  if(choiceentry == 6)
                  {
                     //Exit if user entered 6
                     System.exit(0);
                  }
                }

                if (hasAnswered == true){
                    hasAnswered == false;
                    //user had issued a valid command, prompt for the next command
                    choiceentry = Enroll.menu(); //Access through the Enroll class
                    if(choiceentry == 6)
                    {
                       //Exit if user entered 6
                       System.exit(0);
                     }
                }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DanielNugent and Tom, thanks for the extra code as well Daniel it was my next point of call! Works perfectly